# Reduce an array of arrays (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have an array of arrays i.e:
 `const arrayDaddy = [[x, 1], [x, 1], [y, 2], [y, 2], [y, 2], [z, 3]]`

my end goal is to take the above `arrayDaddy` and mutate it by adding the number in `arrayDaddy[i][1]` if the two items have the same value `arrayDaddy[i][0]`. Additionally, I want to throw out nested arrays with repeated `arrayDaddy[i][0]` values after they have been added. The desired result of this process on `arrayDaddy` would be as follows:

`arrayDaddy = [[x, 2], [y, 6], [z, 3]]`

I am wondering if there is a way to use `Array.prototype.reduce();` to achieve this. If not, what is a simple way to achieve this goal?

NOTE: not sure if this is important, but all items with the same value in index 0 will share an index 1 value. for example consider [z, 3]. any addition [z, ] items will also have a 3 in index 1.

I did try `reduce();` but did not have success. my code looked something like this:

```
const arrayDaddy = [[x, 1], [x, 1], [y, 2], [y, 2], [y, 2], [z, 3]] ;

arrayDaddy.reduce((arr1, arr2) => {
  if(arr1[0] === arr2[0]){
    arr1[1] += arr2[1]
    // do something here to delete arr2... but I can't use delete on a local variable?
  } else {
    //do nothing, continue to the next arr in arrayDaddy
  }
});
```

I also considered map, but want to avoid creating a new array. I want to mutate the `arrayDaddy`

Comment: I recommend you to use Map. You need the way to know in which index each value will be. If you don't want to use Map and mutate in the same array you will have to have an object that stores the index where each key is located. In case you don't want to save the indices you will have to traverse the array backwards. It's no problem that you sacrifice a little RAM for speed :)

Comment: I ended up using map. This is part of a larger project I'm working on and I think my overarching methodology has been sloppy which is why I wound up in this position to begin with. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reduce` to generate. First you must store the values by the key who is the first element of the subarray. For example, with `Map`. So you will update the `Map` in the reduce and when is completed transform it to an `Array`.

***NOTE:** The elements of the Map are ordered by the creation of their key.*

```js
const arrayDaddy = [["x", 1], ["x", 1], ["y", 2], ["y", 2], ["y", 2], ["z", 3]];

const res = Array.from(arrayDaddy.reduce((p, c) => {
    const prevVal = p.get(c[0]) || 0;
    p.set(c[0], prevVal + c[1])
    return p;
}, new Map()));

console.log(res);
```

**No Map**

If you really don't want use Map you must need to store a reference of subarrays in an object.

```js
const arrayDaddy = [["x", 1], ["x", 1], ["y", 2], ["y", 2], ["y", 2], ["z", 3]];

// _tmp is to store the reference and _idx the current loop index
let _tmp = {};
let _idx = 0;
while (_idx < arrayDaddy.length) {
    // Get current element
    const element = arrayDaddy[_idx];

    // If the item is not stored, must store and skip the element
    if (_tmp[element[0]] === undefined) {
        _tmp[element[0]] = element;
        ++_idx;
        continue;
    }

    // Update value and drop array element
    _tmp[element[0]][1] += element[1];
    arrayDaddy.splice(_idx, 1);
}

console.log(arrayDaddy);
```

**No store reference values**

If you don't want to store any references to save memory you must iterate each element and check if has a previus one to the index to be able to sum the current value and drop the current element.

```js
const arrayDaddy = [["x", 1], ["x", 1], ["y", 2], ["y", 2], ["y", 2], ["z", 3]];

// _idx is one because you don't need process the 0 element
let _idx = 1;
while (_idx < arrayDaddy.length) {
    // Get current element
    const element = arrayDaddy[_idx];

    // Check if has previous element
    let prevFind = false;
    for (let pi = _idx - 1; pi >= 0; --pi) {
        // If find, update value, drop array element and set prevFind flag
        if (arrayDaddy[pi][0] === element[0]) {
            arrayDaddy[pi][1] += element[1];
            arrayDaddy.splice(_idx, 1);
            prevFind = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // No previuos value, go next
    if (!prevFind) {
        ++_idx;
    }
}

console.log(arrayDaddy);
```

Comment: This does work, but I do not understand it haha. What I see: you are making a new array `res` and asking it to be formed by using a reduce function on `arrayDaddy`. So far so good. Next, p is my accumulator, c is the current value. You declare a new const `prevVal` to be either 0 or `p.get(c[0])`. what does the `p.get(c[0])` do here?

Comment: Yes. First, `c` as `current` is the subarray of `arrayDaddy`. So `c[0]` is the `key: "x", "y", ...` and `c[1]` is the `value: 1, 2, ...`. Second `p` is the accumulator and is a `Map`. In the map I'll store the the sum of values of each key. `prevVal ` is the current value accumulated for  the `c[0] key`. In case don't exists (not setted) will we return `undefined`. In that case the `prevVal` will be `0`. After that, I will set a new value for `c[0]` who is the sum of the previous with the current one.

Comment: As aditional. `Array.from` creates with the map iterating it. you could read those links: [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Answer (score 1):

If you have same groups in sequences, you could check the last group and add the value.

```js
const
    [x, y, z] = 'xyz';
    array = [[x, 1], [x, 1], [y, 2], [y, 2], [y, 2], [z, 3]],
    result = array.reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        if (r.at(-1)?.[0] === k) r.at(-1)[1] += v;
        else r.push([k, v]);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```